# h2o max_runtime_seconds - doesn't seem to have any impact?

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to make use of the max_runtime_seconds but either I am having a hard time understanding how exactly this should be work, or what I feel is more likely - there is some sort of bug.

I have been testing with random forests and it never seems to cut down on the runtime.

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
from h2o.estimators import H2ORandomForestEstimator

df=h2o.import_file('covtype.csv') #### https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/covtype/
for i in df.names:
    df[i]=df[i].asfactor()
df.types  ## just showing everything is categorical


train,test = df.split_frame(ratios=[0.75], seed = 2017)

response  = 'C55'
xvars  = train.drop(["C55"]).col_names


mymodel = H2ORandomForestEstimator(
nfolds = 10,
max_runtime_secs = 30,
    stopping_rounds = 5,
    ntrees = 500   
)

mymodel.train(
x = xvars,
y = response,
validation_frame = test,
training_frame = train)
## does not finish remotely close to <30 seconds
mymodel.actual_params()
```

Note that the max run time parameter doesn't seem to be saved and stays at 0.
I'm using the 'bleeding edge' version of h2o right now ~3.13 and python.

Comment: My guess is that `max_runtime_secs` refers to the maximum allocated seconds to run each for each tree. Thus, if you have `ntrees=100`, then the max time to build this model is 100 trees x 90 sec x 5 folds, or 45000 seconds.

Comment: If you'll post a fully reproducible example, it's more likely that someone will try to help you debug the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  You can even copy the one from the docs: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/max_runtime_secs.html  Also adding some code to time the training using the timeit module or similar would help demonstrate if this is actually a bug or not.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr That's a good guess, but no, the docs state that it's the max runtime for the whole model (not each tree).  So indeed the `max_runtime_secs` variable should enforce a time limit of 90 secs in the code above.

Comment: @ErinLeDell  The dataset in that amazon link doesn't seem to load so I can't use it.  Maybe a dataset that is somewhat large so it doesn't converge immediately with the early stopping parameters as this is where I am encountering this issue.   I look at the actual_parameters() and also in the flow online view and I see max_runtime_seconds as 0 still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed that it is a bug with the Python API (the `max_runtime_secs` code is working on the backend and also in the R client).  I opened a ticket [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4702) and I'm hopeful that this will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Ok Erin, thanks beat me to this by a few seconds.  I updated the above with an example using the cover type dataset.  Thanks!